# Android: fill a listview with an object

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am wondering if it is possible to put a list of TextView inside a Listview in Android. I tried this code but the result does not give me the right text wanted. I want to display 20 toto for testing.

Here my Main.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listcontacts);

    // Instanciating an array list (you don't need to do this, 
    // you already have yours).
    List<TextView> contacts = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i< 20; i++)
    {
        TextView toto = new TextView(this);
        toto.setText("toto");
        contacts.add(toto);

    }

    // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a 
    // first parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your 
    // array as a third parameter.
    ArrayAdapter<TextView> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<TextView>(
            this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            contacts );

    listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 
}
```

Then the XML file of main

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listcontacts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 </ListView>
```

Should I need to create a TextView inside my listview and call "findViewById(TextView)" in my class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I need to create a TextView inside my listview and call
>   "findViewById(TextView)" in my class?

No you shouldn't. The Adapter is responsible to adapt your dataset to some sort of visualization. `ArrayAdapter`, for instance, is using the TextView contained into `simple_list_item_1.xml`. In your case, `contacts`, should be an `ArrayList<String>` and the adapter should `Adapter<String>`

Answer (score 0):

Just change your Array of TextView for Strings:

**remove:**

```
  List<TextView> contacts = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i< 20; i++)
    {
        TextView toto = new TextView(this);
        toto.setText("toto");
        contacts.add(toto);

    }
```

and:

```
ArrayAdapter<TextView> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<TextView>(
        this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        contacts );
```

**add:**

```
List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0 ; i< 20; i++)
    {
        contacts.add("toto");

    }
```

and:

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                contacts );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create the `TextViews` the adapter does that for you. Just create

```
List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>(20);
for(int i = 0 ; i< 20; i++) {
    contacts.add("toto");
}
```

And call

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        contacts );
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can create a custom adapter. Or use an String adapter.**

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
   list.add("toto");
}

listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers. I found something on internet and tested it. This is exactly I want to do.

"Using a Custom ArrayAdapter" is the solution I use.

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

In this they create a model with 2 String data.
Then create the template xml you want to show.
And create you adapter to fill data.
Fill data.